# MySQL JOIN and Return the Longest URL per Domain

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to create a joined SELECT statement that returns the longest URL for each domain. Can anyone help me grab the longest `link.page_href` for each domain?

Heres my current SELECT statement.

```
SELECT link.page_href, domain.domain_name
FROM `google_sort_backlink_domains` AS domain
JOIN `google_sort_backlinks` AS link ON link.domain_id = domain.id
WHERE domain.tablekey_id = 22
```

And heres a SQL Fiddle with the scheme and some test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9c7b/7

Right now I get:

```
url, domain1
url, domain1
longest url, domain1
url, domain2
longest url, domain2
```

And what I want is

```
longest url, domain1
longest url, domain2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT link.id, link.page_href, dom.domain_name
FROM( 
  SELECT domain.id, domain.domain_name, max( length( link.page_href )) max_len
  FROM `google_sort_backlink_domains` AS domain
  JOIN `google_sort_backlinks` AS link ON link.domain_id = domain.id
  WHERE domain.tablekey_id = 22
  GROUP BY domain.id, domain.domain_name
) dom
JOIN `google_sort_backlinks` AS link
ON  link.domain_id = dom.id
   AND length( link.page_href ) = dom.max_len
```

Demo ---> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9c7b/43

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,

`SELECT MAX(LENGTH(link.page_href)) GROUP BY domain_id`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9c7b/45 Heres where I tried it. I dont think Im using it correctly, it returns the max length as a column but still returns a random URL.